# Чем обусловлены потери при передаче файлов через сокеты?

Tags: c#, файлы, сокет

Передаю файл.

```
  byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(@spUser);//записываю файл в file
  int lF = file.Length;
  string lFile = "";
  //{тут вычисляю длину файла, которая будет содержаться в строковой переменной lFile}
  byte[] lmsg1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(lFile.ToString());//преобразую в массив byte
  byte[] message1 = new byte[lmsg1.Length + file.Length];//создаю новый массив, который будет содержать: 10 byte- длина file, остальное- сам массив file
  Array.Copy(lmsg1, 0, message1, 0, lmsg1.Length);
  Array.Copy(file, 0, message1, lmsg1.Length, file.Length);
  handler.Send(message1);//отправляю клиенту
```

Принимаю файл:

```
Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);//создаю новый клиент
byte[] bytes = new byte[10];//массив для считывания строки с кол-м байт в файле
int ChByte = sender.Receive(bytes);//принял
int chByteFile = Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, ChByte));//преобразовал в int
byte[] file = new byte[chByteFile];//создал новый массив для считывания файла (ранее- массив file)
ChByte = sender.Receive(file);//принимаю
File.WriteAllBytes(@""+FilePath+FileName+FileExtension, file);//создаю сам файл
```

Файл создается, количество байт в исходном и в принятом одинаково, но принятый файл поврежден. Как с этим бороться? Что предпринять, чтобы потери не было и файл приходил в исходном состоянии?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) какие байты битые? - абсолютно все или после какого-то байта начали приходить битые?

2) а разве в сокетах поток не ограничен по размеру в одном сообщении?

> количество байт в исходном и в принятом одинаково

это всего лишь потому, что считывается количество байт в самом начале, и создается массив по этому размеру.

**p.s.** У меня предположение, что передается первые пару килобайт, а дальше записываются случайные байты системы. Решение - разбить отправляемый файл на несколько сообщений.

Comment: А если попробовать кинуть файлик *.txt объемом ~10 кб, и проверить, когда начинают искажаться данные? Файл *.txt меньше килобайта вчера нормально передался.

Comment: @Tyler я о том же.., просто когда я писал передачу файлов через сокеты (но писал на Delphi), там было ограничения в сокетах 8 кБ, и просто при отправки я делил свое сообщение по 2 кБ и отправлял их, а на приемнике склеивал. Думаю у вас тут такая же проблема...

Comment: текстовый документ более 10 кб передается без потерь!

Comment: Вы были правы, когда размер пакета превышает 25156 байт, остальная часть его теряется! Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: @Tyler пожалуйста :) удачного программерского дня :)

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] message1 = new byte[lmsg1.Length + file.Length];//создаю новый массив, который будет содержать: 10 byte- длина file, остальное- сам массив file
```

А где собственно 10 байт для длины файла? Я вижу лишь сложение двух длин, что уже благополучно завалит клиентскую часть, когда длина строкового представления числа будет меньше или больше 10.

Со стороны сервера Вы отправляете данные один раз, принимать их на стороне клиента почему-то хотите дважды... Могу Вас уверить, что на стороне клиента второй Receive наглухо повесит программу (до таймаута, ну или совсем с концами)

Вот подправленный пример с комментариями:

Сервер.

```
const int headerOffset = 10;

// Socket для сервера
Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0], 11111));
server.Listen(1);
// Ожидаем подсоединение клиента
Socket handler = server.Accept();

// Дождались клиента, подготавливаем передачу
// Файл, который собираемся передать
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\sample.txt");//записываю файл в file

// Количество байт в файле
int lF = file.Length;

// Массив для передачи клиенту, где первые 10 символов - заголовок с длиной файла
byte[] data = new byte[headerOffset + lF];

// Преобразуем длину файла в текст и кладём всё в массив
byte[] encodedLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(lF.ToString());

// Копируем полученный массив в заголовок
Array.Copy(encodedLength, data, encodedLength.Length);
// Копируем байты из файла в массив, начиная с 10 байта
Array.Copy(file, 0, data, headerOffset, file.Length);

handler.Send(data);//отправляю клиенту
```

Клиент.

```
const int headerOffset = 10;

// Сокет для соединения
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

// Соединение с сервером
client.Connect(Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList, 11111);

// Создаём буфер для данных.
// Размер массива равен размеру буфера самого сокета
byte[] data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

// Получаем данные от сервера
// Прошу учесть, что отладку я делал пошагово, соответственно сервер благополучно отправил данные
// а на стороне клиента я их все принял, но на деле никто не даёт никаких гарантий
// что будет передано всё как хочется. Уже упоминали, что TCP просто труба.
int ChByte = client.Receive(data);

// Первые 10 байт и преобразуем их в число
int fileLength = Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, headerOffset));

// Создаём массив для файла
byte[] file = new byte[fileLength];

// Копируем данные, начиная с 10 символа
Array.Copy(data, headerOffset, file, 0, fileLength);
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\newsample.txt", file);
```

Comment: Вы не правы. Данные при передачи через сокеты принимаются потоком, 2-й receive не повесит систему, он примет очередные данные.
проверено, если сначала 2 строки, а потом- файл.

Comment: Это если успеет, а если примет и первое сообщение и второе разом?)

Если со стороны сервера не будет уже данных для отправки, а со стороны клиента поднимется Receive, в случае отсутствия таймаута клиент будет бесконечно ожидать получения данных (либо пока они не появятся, либо пока не отвалится сервер, либо пока не наступит таймаут, если он задан).

Comment: Так а как он примет первое и второе разом, если размер буфера фиксирован?)

Comment: Но я Ваш способ обязательно попробую!

Comment: > Так а как он примет первое и второе разом, если размер буфера фиксирован?)

10 байт для заголовка? А если размер файла будет пару гигабайт, что с буфером делать будете?)

Comment: Разрабатываемая ИС предназначена для передачи приемущественно текстовых документов. Буду в цикле принимать, если пару гигов) Но на это я не рассчитываю.