# В продолжение темы потерь передачи через сокеты

Tags: c#, сокет

Предыдущий вопрос был [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/225683/c-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B)

Проблема, с помощью IVsevolod была найдена, далее отслеживал передачу большого текстового файла 491518 байт, данные передавались:

```
        int len = message1.Length;//длина отправляемого файла
        int totalLength = 0;//счетчик отправленных байт
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
        do
        {
            if (totalLength + 512 <= len) Array.Copy(message1, totalLength, buffer,0, 512);//чтобы отправилось столько, сколько длина message1
            else Array.Copy(message1, totalLength, buffer, 0, len - totalLength);
            int bytesSent = sender.Send(buffer);
            totalLength += 512;
        } while (totalLength < len);//пока не конец файла
```

принимались:

```
        byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
        int bytesRec=handler.Receive(bytes);
        byte[] bytes2 = new byte[16];
        int ChByte = handler.Receive(bytes2);
        string ch = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes2, 0, 6);
        string chF = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes2, 6, 10);
        int chCom = Convert.ToInt32(ch);//размер сообщения в байтах
        int chFile = Convert.ToInt32(chF);//размер файла в байтах
        byte[] bytes1 = new byte[chCom];
        ChByte = handler.Receive(bytes1);//принимаем сообщение

        byte[] file = new byte[chFile];//массив по размеру файла
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];//будем по 512 принимать
        int totalLength=0;
        do
        {
             int a = handler.Receive(buffer);
             if (totalLength + 512 <= chFile) Array.Copy(buffer, 0, file, totalLength, 512);
             else Array.Copy(buffer, 0, file, totalLength, chFile-totalLength);
             totalLength += 512;
        } while (totalLength < chFile);

        File.WriteAllBytes(@""+fileDir + FileName + FileExtension, file);
```

В итоге: файл принимается, но (!) пропадает в конце или 2 (бывало и 5) байт, или добавляются(неизвестно откуда) 1-  8 байт. То есть, я брал 40960 строк с содержанием каждой "1234567890" и уже отслеживал. 
приходит: или последняя (40960) строка 12345678
Или + 1-8 байт

Чаще всего не доходит 2 байта.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с похожей проблемой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потерь-то нет никаких, есть ошибки приёма или отправки)

Проверок Вы как-то много повесили, зачем все эти сложения с 512?

```
        // Создаём буфер для данных.
        // Размер массива равен размеру буфера самого сокета
        byte[] data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        // Получаем заголовок
        int ChByte = client.Receive(data, 10, SocketFlags.None);
        // Первые 10 байт и преобразуем их в число
        int fileLength = Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, headerOffset));
        // Создаём массив для файла
        byte[] file = new byte[fileLength];

        int offset = 0; // Сдвиг для массива с получаемым файлом
        int bytes = 0; // Количество байт прочитанных из сокета
        do
        {
            // Читаем сколько-то байт из сокета
            bytes = client.Receive(data);
            // Копируем полученные байты в конец массива с файлом
            Array.Copy(data, 0, file, offset, bytes);
            // Сдвигаем конец массива
            offset += bytes;
        }
        while (offset < fileLength);
```

И никаких проблем с полученным файлом...

Замечу при этом, что неважно, каким образом будет производиться отправка файла, сразу весь или по кусочкам. Размер того, что нам необходимо получить мы и так знаем из заголовка.

Comment: IMHO после

    bytes = client.Receive(data);

неплохо бы добавить

   if (bytes <= 0)
     break;

или что-то в таком духе (я C# не знаю), чтобы не висеть при преждевременном закрытии сокета клиентом.

Comment: Все бы хорошо, только надо не забыть проверку на остаток от деления на длину буфера. И предыдущий комментарий не брать во внимание.
It work!