# Как решить проблему повреждения файла передоваемого socket 'ом

Tags: java, c#, сокет

Сервер на java, клиент на c#. Получает файл клиент от сервера, но файл повреждён. Передача файла происходит при помощи сокета и технологии tcp/ip.

Пример повреждённого файла:
[image]

Фрагмент кода отправки файла java:

```
 try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + socket);
            //connection established successfully


            //имч файла в массив байтов
            byte [] filenm =  filename.getBytes();
           dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
           //отправка имени

            dOut1 = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            int filenom =  filenm.length;
            String str = Integer.toString(filenom);
            byte [] filenom3 =  str.getBytes();


            //отправка числа
           dOut1.write(filenom3);

            //отправка имени

           dOut.write( filenm);


            //creating object to send file
            File file = new File (fileLocation);
            byte [] byteArray  = new byte [(int)file.length()];
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
            bufferedInputStream.read(byteArray,0,byteArray.length); // copied file into byteArray

            //sending file through socket
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Sending " + fileLocation + "( size: " + byteArray.length + " bytes)");
            outputStream.write(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);           //copying byteArray to socket
            outputStream.flush();                                       //flushing socket
            System.out.println("Done.");                                //file has been sent
        }
```

Фрагмент кода клиента c#:

```
 //получение файла
            byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 5000];
            string receivedPath = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\"+ fileName;
            Console.WriteLine(receivedPath + fileName);
            int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);
            Console.WriteLine("Client:{0} connected & File {1} started received", clientSock.RemoteEndPoint, receivedPath);
            BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath, FileMode.Append));//receivedPath, FileMode.Append)
            bWrite.Write(clientData);//clientData
            Console.WriteLine("File:received & saved at path:" +  receivedPath);
            bWrite.Close();
            clientSock.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Предполагаю, что это связанно с буфером обмена и неправильной записью  в него т.к изменяется вес файла. Выяснил, что клиент может принимать через буфер файлы не больше 64кб.
Подсказали, что проблему можно решить циклом и разложением файла на пакеты по 64кб, но я не знаю как это реализовать. 
Как исправить данную ситуацию? Приветствуются примеры кода.

Comment: пробовали считывать в цикле пока не начнёте получать нулл?

Comment: Не могли бы вы написать поконкретнее, что необходимо сделать. Выяснилось, что файлы проходят без повреждения, у который вес < 64кб

Comment: проблема остаётся актуальной

Comment: Где вы увидели такой способ приема файла по TCP? Сожгите эту книгу и купите нормальный учебник.

Comment: @PavelMayorov гнобить каждый горазд, предложили бы лучше вместо своего бесполезного комментария объективное решение проблемы

Comment: @Exodium я уже кучу раз про это рассказывал, еще раз рассказывать лень. А где учат так принимать файлы - мне тоже интересно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov если Вы рассказывали, так дайте ссылку на обсуждение, чтобы TC смог почитать и решить свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приветствую!

В этой ветке форума решена проблема передачи файла размером 650 мб через TCP соединение.

http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread564413.html

#### Сервер:

```
class Server {
    private TcpListener listener { get; set; }
    private NetworkStream stream { get; set; }

    public Server()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1488);
        listener.Start();
        new Thread(ListenForClients).Start();
    }

    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = this.listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            new Thread(HandleClient).Start(client);
        }
    }

    private void HandleClient(object tcpClient)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)tcpClient;
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            Recieve(client);
        }
    }

    private void Recieve(TcpClient client)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        try
        {
            stream = client.GetStream();
            int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 12);
            if(bytesRead == 0) return;

            ushort id = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);
            long len = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 2);
            ushort nameLen = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 10);
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, nameLen);
            string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, nameLen);

            if (id == 1)
            {
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    int recieved = 0;
                    while (recieved < len)
                    {
                        bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                        recieved += bytesRead;
                        writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes recieved.", recieved);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("File length: {0}", len);
                Console.WriteLine("File Name: {0}", fileName);
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Клиент:

```
private static TcpClient client;
private static NetworkStream stream;
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string temp;
    client = new TcpClient("localhost", 1488);
    stream = client.GetStream();
    Console.WriteLine(client.SendBufferSize);

    while ((temp = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit")
    {
        Send(temp);
    }

    SendFile(new FileInfo(@"File_path"));
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

public static void SendFile(FileInfo file)
{
    byte[] id = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)1);
    byte[] size = BitConverter.GetBytes(file.Length);
    byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.Name);
    byte[] fileNameLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)fileName.Length);
    byte[] fileInfo = new byte[12 + fileName.Length];

    id.CopyTo(fileInfo, 0);
    size.CopyTo(fileInfo, 2);
    fileNameLength.CopyTo(fileInfo, 10);
    fileName.CopyTo(fileInfo, 12);

    stream.Write(fileInfo, 0, fileInfo.Length); //Размер файла, имя

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 32];
    int count;

    long sended = 0;

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open))
        while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            sended += count;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sended.", sended);
        }
    stream.Flush();
}


private static void Send(string message)
{
    byte[] id = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)0);
    byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    byte[] msgLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)msg.Length);
    byte[] fileInfo = new byte[12 + msg.Length];

    id.CopyTo(fileInfo, 0);
    msgLength.CopyTo(fileInfo, 10);
    msg.CopyTo(fileInfo, 12);

    stream.Write(fileInfo, 0, fileInfo.Length);
    stream.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решилась, благодаря небольшому фрагменту кода из примеров выше.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте прочитать файл в массив байтов таким образом:

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

Comment: И вот еще будет полезно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/225683/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B?rq=1

Comment: к сожалению, это не предотвратило повреждение файла.

Comment: как я понял, на получение файла стоит ограничение, >64кб файлы повреждаются

Comment: Попробуйте разбить исходный массив на куски по 64 Кб, а на клиенте склеивать.

Comment: а как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: byte[] buffer = new byte[64000];
Далее в цикле двигаешься по совему массиву, заполняешь buffer и передаешь на клиент.

Comment: каков размер исходного файла и каков принятого? пробовали сравнивать содержимое, чтобы убедиться, что файл просто обрезается?

Comment: так и есть, он обрезается.  размер исходного 250кб, а получаемый становится равен 64кб

Comment: Привести пример кода не могу, ибо нет.
1. Здесь написано о java NIO и в частности о SocketChannel http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/socketchannel.html
2. На стороне сервера читайте файл по кускам размером по 64 кб (попробуйте MappedByteBuffer) и отправляйте по сети
2. На клиенте читайте из сокета до тех пор, пока получаете полностью заполненный буфер определенного размера (если пустой или частично заполнен, значит передача закончилась).

Comment: проблема решена, благодарю за помощь и проявленный интерес к теме.